# Play video using mplayer after buffering is completed

Tags: mplayer

I am using mplayer in my application to play online video. But if the internet connection is slow it stops in the middle. I was wondering can we play an online video using mplayer once it has buffered 100%. How?

Comment: Yes .. sure .. But my requirement is if the video is being played for the first time, download it as well as play in online in parallel. And in case of a slow internet connection, the video will buffer. So, in such case .. if my video is 100% buffered .. then I shall play it.

Comment: @ron123456 Are you using the 2 necessary options for MPlayer: `-cache xxxxx -cache-min xx`?